# asp.net validation. What is the RegularExpression for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to allow only 9 numbers without any letters and the letter 'V' at the last. Altogether 10 digits.

Eg - 123456789V, 675645238V

not allowed letters other than 'V' or 'v' at the end.

What is the Expression should I use?

Comment: what have you tried so far? and also so is not for providing the source codes for the questions. please read the guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex will be (exactly 9 digits and `V` or `v` in the end):

```
^[0-9]{9}[Vv]$
```

If in the beginning or end can be some other symbols (to much something like this - `aaa123456789Vbbbb`):

```
[0-9]{9}[Vv]
```

Comment: Why do you use ^ at the first and ended with $ ?

Comment: `^` means that string must start from the symbol after this one. `$` means that it is the end of the string. Without this symbols you can put any symbols before and after matching string and regex will find a match. See my edited answer - the first regex for value `aaaa123456789Vaaa` won't find a match, but second will. With this symbols string should exactly match pattern and no other symbols can be in that string.